# How to get cofficients in DFT?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, dft, dct

In my recent study of signal processing I came to know that we can compress images/signal using DFT/DCT. If we consider the lossy compression of audio or any image then it follows the same steps:

1. Apply DCT/DFT on N samples of data.
2. Collect coefficients which contains most of the signal energy i.e., a signal's DCT representation tends to have more of its energy concentrated in a small number of **coefficients** when compared to other transforms like the DFT.

But I have doubt that how to get these coefficients. In DFT we have 
$$ {\tt ORIGINAL:}\ X(e^{jw})=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2{\pi}/Nn}\\
{\tt CORRECTED:}\ X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2{\pi}/Nnk}
  $$

Here, $ \omega $ is a continuous variable. Then how to extract coefficients when $ \omega $ is a continuous variable?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  What you have in your equation is the [Discrete-Time Fourier Transform](http://www.dspguide.com/ch10/6.htm).  That is not usually what is used: note that this requires infinite data... which is hard to store.  [The DFT is something else.](http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/1.htm)

Comment: sorry for that..I have edited it

Comment: Well, let me correct what you've done and you'll see.

Comment: Note that you missed out a $k$ (discrete frequency variable) in your edit.